# I need to track picklist value chanages from record using event monitoring is that possible

Tags: apex, rest-api, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

Using Rest api i have tried using work bench

> /services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/describe

This is returing api  "picklistValues" : [ ],

Comment: What do you need to do after monitoring? Do processing on other objects? Show in UI? or any other use case?

Comment: hi can we make json structure and show in response body

Comment: Didnt understand what you mean by `make json structure and show in response body` ? Can you [edit] question to include exact details what you are trying to achieve